# Storing clustering result

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Given my pandas `df`, I am doing hierarchical clustering of the correlation matrix as follows:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch

X = df.corr().values
d = sch.distance.pdist(X) 
L = sch.linkage(d, method='complete')
C = sch.fcluster(L, 0.5*d.max(), 'distance')
```

I need help performing the following simple task. I would like a new `df_res` with two columns: (1) The name of the variable as given by the columns of my original `df`, (2) the cluster that it belongs to based on the results in `C`. Something like:

```
VAR     CLUSTER
var_1   1
var_2   2
var_3   1
var_4   1
var_5   2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create desired dataframe like this

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame([{'VAR': x, 'CLUSTER': y} for (x,y) in zip(df.columns, C)])
```